# How to show code window full screen next to Groups and Files

Tags: xcode

Xcode seems to split the code window and show the file name in the top segment and then the code in the bottom segment.  Does anyone know how to set it permanently so that that only the code window is shown on the right and then Groups and Files on the left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift+Command+E hides the top segment. The state of the window will be remembered, so it is kind of permanently.

Comment: Xcode doesn't seem to remember this setting - I keep finding that I need to go set it again...

Comment: The setting is project dependent, stored in the .pbxuser file inside the .xcodeproj package. If you have the the problem with a single project, then the cause might be that you overwrite your .pbxuser from a shared repository.